# How to bulk check empty strings for many variables?

Tags: java

I have this type of code:

```
HashMap out = new HashMap();
if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(foo.a)) {
    out.put(A.A_NAME, foo.a);
}
if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(foo.b)) {
    out.put(B.B_NAME, foo.b);
}
if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(foo.c)) {
    out.put(C.C_NAME, foo.c);
}
//... many continues here
```

Is there a faster way of writing all these code?

Comment: What are A,B,C? Enums?

Comment: @assylias `A.A_NAME`,etc. are final static field in `A`,.. classes

Comment: Does foo only contain these static fields?

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk No foo is a data class that does not contain static fields... `A`,`B`,`C` are classes that contains only final static fields

Comment: Why not change the data structure to hold a list(or map) of strings as opposed to a bunch of individual data members? This would make it incredibly easy and you wouldn't have data organization issues that will resort to either a lot of copy pasta code or reflection.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk because it is from an API package...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fields are not `static` then you could do:

```
Test t= new Test();
for (Field field : t.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (field.getType().equals(String.class) && !((String)field.get(t)).isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(field.get(t));
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if they are `static` use `null` instead of `t`:

```
field.get(null)
```

Comment: I was expecting some reflection here... and yes!

Comment: @texasbruce It results in less lines of code but it won't be faster, which was your question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a faster way of doing this?

In terms of performance, no.  (Or at least ... the scope for improvement is probably not worth bothering about.)

In terms of lines of code and readability, you could refactor the code by writing and using a method like this:

```
private void addIfNonempty(HashMap map, String name, String value) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
        map.put(name, value);
    }
}

addIfNonempty(out, A.A_NAME, foo.a);
addIfNonempty(out, B.B_NAME, foo.b);
// etcetera
```

You could also use reflection to implement this.  Depending on what the criteria are for identifying the fields to be "added", this could reduce (or eliminate) the repetitious code.  But the performance is likely to be *an order of magnitude* slower, and the code *could* be fragile; e.g. if fields are added or removed ... or the "pattern" is broken.

---

> Is there a faster way of writing all these code?

It really depends on the exact details of the "repetitiveness" ... and also on your IDE / editor skills.  For instance, if your IDE supports something like emacs keyboard macros, you can effectively generate the source code from the field names.  If you were adept at it, you could probably do that in less time than it takes to write and test a reflective version.

Comment: Actually doing a check like string!=null && string.equals("") might be a little faster than using StringUtils.isEmpty if the method isn't inlined.

Comment: That may be true, but the difference is likely to be down in the noise.  (This is why you should always "profile first" ...)

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Either you call it often and it *will* be inlined (it is way shorter than the inlining size threshold) or you don't and it does not matter...

Comment: I agree.  Also not using utility methods like isEmpty hurts readability of code.  Just thought I'd bring it up.